# Query for a specific type of phone number from MongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb

> I need to query only a specific type of phone number from a
>   collection. The following query is MySQL query. How will be the
>   MongoDB query for this purpose.

```
SELECT *
FROM contact_number
WHERE (
  LEFT(phone,4)='+880' OR
  LEFT(phone,5)='00880' OR
  LEFT(phone,3)='880' OR
  LEFT(phone,2)='01'
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$regex` for that. Your requirement's regex format is `^(\+880|00880|880|01)`. So your query should be like this:

```
db.collection.find({ "phone": { $regex: /^(\+880|00880|880|01)/ } });
```